# How to convert a list of number to html in Python?

Tags: python

hey guys, my last problem ^^ say i have a string which contains html, like

```
html = '<td class="p11_666699"><strong>100</strong></td>'
```

and a list like

```
numbers = [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 
           113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125,
           126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138,
           139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150]
```

basically i want to do something like this:

```
html = '<td class="p11_666699"><strong>' + numbers + '</strong></td>'
```

edit: for some reason the code tags add curly brackets when i post this, so it messes up, sorry.

Comment: This question needs a better title.

Comment: This question needs a better question, I have no idea what he wants.

Comment: I think you should just output:
<html><body><h1>42</h1></body></html>

Comment: Please provide the ACTUAL HTML that would be a correct answer.  The actual HTML that you would say is your expected, correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, it's really hard to understand your question... but if you want to generate a bunch of table cells, each containing one of the numbers, use something like this:

```
html = ''.join('<td>%d</td>' % n for n in numbers)
```

Of course you can add in a `class` or other attribute to be applied to the table cells if you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think you either want this:

```
numbers = [100, 101, 102, 103]
output = "<td>" + ", ".join(map(str, numbers)) + "</td>"
```

or

```
output = ""
for number in numbers:
    output += "<td>" + str(number) + "</td>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a way to join a list of numbers into a string? This will work:

```
' '.join(map(str, [10, 20, 30]))
```

Resulting in:

```
'10 20 30'
```

The second argument of `map` is a list, so you can place your 'numbers' list there.

This is in no way HTML specific, of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
html = ['<td class="p11_666699"><strong>%d</strong></td>' % number for number in numbers]
```

And I see David just suggested this (but joined).